# FOR com URL de arquivo getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Preciso fazer um `FOR` com arquivo getJSON. Como é a forma correta?

```js
selectOcorrencias = $.getJSON("http://izicondominios.com.br/appOperacoes.php?operacao=selectOcorrencias&condominioID=2");


for (seOcor in selectOcorrencias){
  document.write(selectOcorrencias[seOcor].ID_Ocorrencia + selectOcorrencias[seOcor].morador + "<br />");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de passar uma callback para o `.getJSON` poder retornar os dados. Podes ter na mesma esse ciclo `for` mas ele tem de estar dentro da callback, pois o `.getJSON` é assíncrono e vai passar o JSON que queres somente para a callback.

O código poderá ser assim:

```js
$.getJSON("http://izicondominios.com.br/appOperacoes.php", function(selectOcorrencias){
    for (var seOcor in selectOcorrencias){
      document.write(selectOcorrencias[seOcor].ID_Ocorrencia + selectOcorrencias[seOcor].morador + "<br />");
    }
});
```

Nota: Se o URL fôr para ser usado no mesmo dominio, então deves retirar o dominio e usar somente `/appOperacoes.php`. Dessa maneira evitas que o pedido ajax seja interpretado como "de outro dominio" e seja bloqueado por [CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129).